# html php MySQL insert multiple rows into db from a repeating html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am new to php and my sql. Looking for some advice. 
I have a form that repeats to display each game in a database for a specific week. I have added radio buttons to the away and home team. In the form is displaying fine, but what I want to do is when submit is clicked, I want each row to be added to the database where the selected team and the game number are submitted.

The problem I'm having is that only one row is getting submitted, and the radio buttons aren't sending the value unless I leave the radio button the original name but then each repeating row is under one big group so I can't select a winner for each game, only one for the whole form.

Any advice would be great, I need to find out how to somehow store each rows values into arrays and then loop through the arrays to insert them into the database

Comment: Share the relevant code ??

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone so I don't have a copy of the code. But it's a pretty simple form. I just don't know how to store the values of each form row into an array and then how to insert the array data into MySQL so that each row inserts as a table row. And how to change the radio button group name so that the selected values displays the value of the winner

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="game[]"/>
```

like to store values of checkboxes in array. But better if you could share the relevant code.